# Why Am I not receiving the email Approval Request

Tags: email, approval-process

Why am I not receiving the  email alerts for approval request?

I am the approver. my Email deliverability  is set to "All mail".

Receive approval request is set to "Only if I am the approver"
My email address is verified  and I'm an active user.

Thank you

Comment: 1.Did you checked your **spam box?** 2.Invoke a test mail(this is to check the deliverability functioning correctly) 3.Check the outbound messages to see if the approval request emails are being sent out from Salesforce. It will have the logs of the mail being sent by salesforce

Comment: Google recently announced that they're doubling down on DKIM requirements when accepting email - if your sender address is from your company's domain and you don't have that setup it might be the reason for emails not getting delivered.